# How to configure webpack 4 to not bundle multiple scss entry points

Tags: node.js, webpack, sass

Hi I have a webpack config that takes multiple scss file based on a glob entry and a main typescript file. The problem is that it bundles the scss file together in one css file while I want them to be individual based on entry.
Webpack is definitely seeing all the files from the glob.
[image]

And the file produced is a bundle of all 3.
I have spent literally hours and hours googling and trying to configure this and its driving me crazy :rage:

Everything I can find shows how to configure multiple outputs while specifying them manually. Or for an older version of the webpack with an unsupported plugin.

Here's my current config:

```
import * as webpack from "webpack";
import * as path from "path";
import * as glob from "glob";
import * as MiniCssExtractPlugin from "mini-css-extract-plugin";

const config: webpack.Configuration = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: glob.sync(
    "./src/themes/**/scss/*.main.scss",
    "./src/ts/theme-pack.ts"
  ),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".css", ".ts", ".scss"]
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist")
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[name].css"
    })
  ]

  //   //Dev server
  //   devServer: {
  //     contentBase: __dirname,
  //     compress: true,
  //     port: 8080
  // }
};

export default config;
```

Can anyone help? This seems like it should be really simple but…

## Edit

Here's what I have going. Only problem is that it produces js files with same name as the css. And I can't find a way of getting the css into `./dist/css` and the js in to `./dist/js`

```
import * as webpack from "webpack";
import * as path from "path";
import * as glob from "glob";
import * as MiniCssExtractPlugin from "mini-css-extract-plugin";


let entries = {
  "theme-pack": "./src/ts/theme-pack.ts"
};

function getEntries() {
  const files = glob.sync("./src/themes/**/scss/*.main.scss");
  files.forEach(file => {
    entries[path.basename(file)] = file;
  });
  return entries;
}

function perName() {
  // this function will create Objects that can splitChunks
  // testing each file in its own location
  return glob
    .sync("./src/themes/**/scss/*.main.scss")
    .reduce((obj, filename) => {
      const niceName = path.basename(filename);
      obj[niceName] = {
        test: new RegExp(filename),
        name: niceName,
        chunks: "all",
        enforce: true
      };
      return obj;
    }, {});
}

const config: webpack.Configuration = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: getEntries(),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".css", ".ts", ".scss"]
  },

  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
    })
  ],
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: perName()
    }
  }

  //   //Dev server
  //   devServer: {
  //     contentBase: __dirname,
  //     compress: true,
  //     port: 8080
  // }
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it there are 2 options here to achieve this.

#### 1) Using splitChunks

```js
optimization: {
  splitChunks: {
    cacheGroups: {
      adminLteStyles: {
        name: 'admin-lte',
        test: /admin-lte\.main\.scss$/,
        chunks: 'all',
        enforce: true
      },
      coreUiStyles: {
        name: 'coreui',
        test: /coreui\.main\.scss$/,
        chunks: 'all',
        enforce: true
      },
      
      // ... more
      
    }
  }
},
```

But as you can see this requires to write a regex block for every css file you have... Of course you can create a function that takes care of that...

```js
function perTheme() {
  // this function will create Objects that can splitChunks
  // testing if the file is located under a specific theme directory
  return glob.sync("./src/themes/*/")
    .reduce((obj, theme) => {
      const niceName = path.basename(theme)
      obj[niceName] = {
        test: new RegExp(theme + "(.*).main.scss"),
        name: niceName,
        chunks: 'all',
        enforce: true
      }
      return obj;
    }, {})
}

function perName() {
  // this function will create Objects that can splitChunks
  // testing each file in its own location
  return glob.sync("./src/themes/*/scss/*.main.scss")
    .reduce((obj, filename) => {
      const niceName = path.basename(filename)
      obj[niceName] = {
        test: new RegExp(filename),
        name: niceName,
        chunks: 'all',
        enforce: true
      }
      return obj;
    }, {})
}

// in your webpack config ...


optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: perTheme()
      // this will create one css file per theme
      // admin-lte theme etc..
    }
}

// OR

optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: perName()
      // this will create one css file per scss you have
    }
}
```

I understand that this can be tricky to configure, but keep in mind that splitting chunks with this method is very powerful. There are so many ways that you can split your files with this approach. If you feel this is too much check the second option!

#### 2) Using extract-loader

```js
module: {
  rules: [{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [{
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: "[name]-dist.[ext]",
        },
      },
      'extract-loader',
      "css-loader",
      "sass-loader"
    ]
  }]
}
```

So, instead of using `MiniCssExtractPlugin` you can simply use the above configuration. With this, each `scss` file will be converted to `css`, every import will be resolved and then with `extract-loader` you will get the raw `css` in a string format. After that `file-loader` will output a file with this raw `css`. So you will end up with every `scss` file being converted to each `css` equal. But as you can see this simple method gives you a lot less ways to split chunks that the first method!

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! I was trying something similar but couldn't get it to work. I had to loop over the glob and add it to the entries to make it work. Only problem is it produces a js file with the same name as the css. And I cannot get it to export the css and js in to their sub directories of `./dist/css` and `./dist/js`. It seems to be ignoring `compilerOptions.outDir` in ` tsconfig.json` I've edited my post with the latest config.